# Counting nodes in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml file is like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="form.xsl"?>
  <Letter xmlns:xsi="http://www.irica.com/ECEP/1383-12/SendSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:ECEP_Letter.xsd">    
   ...
    <Keywords>
        <Keyword>A</Keyword>
        <Keyword>B</Keyword>
        <Keyword>C</Keyword>
 </Keywords>
 </Letter>
```

Now I want to count number of `Keyword` and put them in a table like this:

### No. | keyword

1    |  A

2    |  B

3    |  C

I've written this code so far:

```
  ...
  </table>
 <h2>keywords: <xsl:value-of select="count(/Letter/Keywords/Keyword)"/></h2>
 <table border="2">
    <tr >
    <th style="text-align:right">No.</th>
    <th style="text-align:right">keyword</th>

  </tr>
     <xsl:for-each select="Letter/Keywords/Keyword">

    <tr>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="Keyword" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>

  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
...
```

It prints total number of keywords but in the table it only prints `A`,`B`,`C` but not the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that you actually want to *count* them - merely *number* them, which can be done easily by:

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="Letter/Keywords/Keyword">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
```

Do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
```